# What are the differences between these states of an IHandler?

Tags: eclipse

`org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler.isEnabled()`

`org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler.isHandled()`

`org.eclipse.ui.handlers.IHandlerService.activateHandler(String, IHandler, Expression)`

According to the above methods, an `IHandler` could have six states, enabled or not, handled or not, activated or not. So many states are confusing. I read some of the source code and documentation, but still don't know enough to distinguish them well.

What are they used for? Is there a correlation?

Comment: To my understanding, `isEnabled()` and `isHandled()` are independent things. `isEnabled()` is whether it is turned on or off. `isHandled()` returns `true`, except if there is a handler to which everything will be [delegated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Language_support_for_delegation), then `isHandled()` returns whether there is a handler to which it can be delegated. See for example `org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction`.

Comment: Activation is also separate. A command often has multiple handlers which are activated under different conditions, only one is normally active.